# PHP: foreach loop result print manay time

Tags: php, foreach

I have a txt file whose name is singles.txt.  Each line contains info about user (name, gender... sepearated by a comma) From the name which is inputed keyborad I want to check this user is wheter exist or not
I do followwing: crreate a object current user then compare it with all object in txt file.This is myfunction.php file

```
<?php
  class User
  {
    public $name;
    public $gender;
    public $age;
    public $personality;
    public $FAVos;
    public $min;
    public $max;
  }
  function countLine() {
      $linecount = 0;
      $file = fopen("singles.txt", "r");
  while(!feof($file)){
    $line = fgets($file);
    $linecount++;
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $linecount;
  }
  function makeCurrentUser($n) {
    $file = fopen("singles.txt", "r");
    while(!feof($file)){
      $line = fgets($file);
      $word = explode(",", $line);
      if ($word[0] == $n) {
        break;  
        fclose($file);
        }
    }
    $currUser = new User();
    $currUser-> name=$word[0];
    $currUser-> gender=$word[1];
    $currUser-> age=$word[2];
    $currUser-> personality=$word[3];
    $currUser-> FAVos=$word[4];
    $currUser-> min=$word[5];
    $currUser-> max=$word[6];
    return $currUser;
    }
    function getAllUser() {
      $file = fopen("singles.txt", "r");
      $collectionUser = array();
      $linecount= countLine();
      while(!feof($file)){
          $line = fgets($file);
          $word = explode(",", $line);
          for ($i=0; $i<= $linecount; $i++) {
             $nameUsr = $i.' user';
             $nameUsr= new User();
             $nameUsr-> name=$word[0];
             $nameUsr-> gender=$word[1];
             $nameUsr-> age=$word[2];
             $nameUsr-> personality=$word[3];
             $nameUsr-> FAVos=$word[4];
             $nameUsr-> min=$word[5];
             $nameUsr-> max=$word[6];
      array_push($collectionUser,$nameUsr);
        }   
     }
     return $collectionUser; 
    }

?>
```

And in anothorr file  (which handle data "name" from keyborad), I call my function and do compare

```
<?
    $name = $_GET['name'];
        $currUser = makeCurrentUser($name);
        $collectionUser= getAllUser();
        foreach ($collectionUser as $user) {
            $common = similar_text($currUser->personality, $user->personality);
            if($currUser->gender!=$user->gender && $currUser->min <= $user->age && $currUser->max >= $user->age
                && $currUser->FAVos== $user->FAVos && $common>=2) {
            echo '<div class="match">';
                echo '<img src="files/user.jpg">';
                echo '<span>';
                echo '<ul>';
                echo '<li>'.$user->name.'</li>';
                echo '<li>'.$user->gender.'</li>';
                echo '<li>'.$user->age.'</li>'; 
                echo '<li>'.$user->personality.'</li>'; 
                echo '<li>'.$user->FAVos.'</li>';   
                echo '</span>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
?>
```

I found the result. It;s ok but each result printed many times. Can you help me what I do wrong

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean - what exactly gets printed many times where?

Comment: It seem that the number it print is equal the line of the txt file

Comment: I don't understand what that means, can you edit the question and add an example?

Comment: My problem is that the result in comparison in foreach loop will print many time

Comment: And the number of the result which printed is equal the number of object I get from txt file

Comment: One result I recieve was print many time. Can you understand my problem

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a `while` and a `for` loop in `getAllUser()` where you would need only  one. Both loops do the same thing, they walk through every line of the file

Comment: Ok solved it I intialiise only $Id then incement it. Thanks for your help